# Making an app with data of different websites

Tags: android, ios, webview, uiwebview

I am making an android app for news sites. I am using APIs of different sites but I also wanna give the list of news websites. I want to inflate those sites in my app in a webview.

So, Do i need to take permission from news channels for opening their websites in my app?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those API's are published publicly then there is no need to take permission from them. As your app is making and creating more user of their channel.

Comment: I hope it clears your confusion. Happy programming :)

Comment: I am using APIs of some sites . I am also adding the list of channels that are avilable and user can open the channel's website directly in the app(i.e, in the webview).

Comment: So , do i need to ask the company for opening their websites in my app ?

Comment: Then you are good to go. You do not have to take permission from them in this case. This is not  against the rules or not a violation of rules.

Comment: ok, means i can open anyone's site in my app without permission, Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73345/discussion-between-andrahul-and-ghost-talker).